# Using Windows Batch Files to split large "Wrapped" files

Tags: string, file, batch-file, split, edi

I need a method to split files into multiple (or even half) based on KB not on number of lines.

I am a Senior EDI Analyst and wrapped data tends to show up as one single long line. Every "solution" I find splits based on number of lines. I need something that will split based on size.

The end-goal is to "Unwrap" this data, meaning each segment will be on its own line. To do this I need to change the delimiters (as there are "special characters" as delimiters).

I do have a solution for that (see below), but for some reason this will not work on files larger than 10 KB. If you know anything about EDI, that's not very big.

I need to find a solution to split files into smaller files of about 5KB each (then I can use the string replacement and re-combine them myself).

Does anyone have an idea of how I might accomplish this with one, huge line?

(Sorry I have to remove the code I placed here only as AN EXAMPLE because someone flagged this as a duplicate WITHOUT READING IT. Please read above and advise.)

Comment: Is PowerShell ok for you instead of cmd  batch?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244063/how-can-i-split-a-binary-file-into-chunks-with-certain-size-with-batch-script-wi

Comment: I've actually never used PowerShell. 
I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise. 

If I can call it from a Batch File I am fine with it. Please advise.

Comment: npocmaka,
I'm only able to use Batch, not Java on this system. 
Only things that are installed with Windows.

Comment: This needs to be automated and without interference. Sure I could just replace delimiters in a text editor, but I need this to be fully automated.

Comment: JavaScript is available by default on windows - way better than trying to make a BAT script do this. Why is this the same code as for a different question you asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707991/replace-strings-or-characters-in-files-using-windows-batch-scripts-over-10-kb

Comment: JavaScript and Java aren't even remotely the same language...

Comment: So your requirements are that this process needs to be automated on a freshly installed Windows 7 Enterprise machine with no other software present? As @Crypt32 stated, Powershell might be available and it should be possible to have a single script to unwrap each file as it is (though harder if you're expecting to determine the segment terminators from each file, or if you have multiple interchanges per file).  If you're splitting the files first in an automated way, you'd also need to ensure you can put them back together in the correct order after unwrapping.

Comment: You could `find` or `findstr` to replace the special character delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Although your description is extensive, there are multiple points that are not clear. There are too many unrelated details that just deviates from the core point of the problem. If each segment in the line is separated by a `|` delimiter (you did not explained this point, but it is assumed from the example code) and you want to split the file based on a certain KB size (you did not specified how many KB), then a segment may be splitted in two different files. Also, I don't understand how changing the `|` delimiters by asterisks may help to solve the problem. After read this question several times, I *assumed* that the problem is this:

> > "Split a file that just contain a very long line (with not a single CR+LF pair) into segments delimited by `|` character, so each segment will be on its own line".

The Batch file below is a solution for *this* problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :ProcessFile  < input.txt  > output.txt
goto :EOF


:ProcessFile
set "previous="

:nextChunk
rem Read the next 1023-bytes chunk
set /P "chunk="
if errorlevel 1 goto endOfFile

rem Break segment if previous one ends at a chunk limit
if "!chunk:~0,1!" equ "|" if defined previous (
   echo !previous!
   set "previous="
)

rem Extract each segment from the chunk and place it on its own line
set "last="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (^"!chunk:^|^=^
% This line separate segments by the given delimiter %
!^") do (

   if defined last echo !last!
   set "last=!previous!%%a"
   set "previous="

)
set "previous=!last!"
goto nextChunk

:endOfFile
rem Show the last segment
if defined previous echo !previous!

exit /B
```

---

**EDIT**: *JScript solution added*

As others have mentioned, you may also use a solution based on JScript, that is a standard programming language preinstalled in all Windows versions from XP on. In this way, the solution is really simple, because you just need to insert the following two lines in your Batch file:

```
echo WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.Stdin.ReadAll().replace(/\^|/g,"\r\n")) > replace.js
cscript //nologo replace.js  < input.txt  > output.txt
```

This is a very simple, but powerful method that you may use in other similar replace operations; just read the corresponding [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0kbytzc(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: 1) I do apologize for my lack of clarity. I'm new to the group, but that's not a good excuse. I see now how I was unclear on this.

2) This code is excellent. I'm going to play around with it to see what I can do. Thank you very much for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot process files > 10k byte is because batch variables (and command lines) are limited to ~8191 bytes.

You are attacking the problem in an inefficient way. Rather than look for a way to split a file into chunks so that you can use your slow batch "solution", you should be looking for a tool that allows you to work with the large files directly, without resorting to splitting, processing, and re-assembly.

As others have stated, PowerShell, JavaScript, and VBS are all good scripting languages that can solve your problem, and they are native to Windows.

If your files are all less than 1 gigabyte in length, then I suggest you try [JREPL.BAT - a regex text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required. Full documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged help.

To Unwrap a file, translating `|` into `*\r\n` (\r is carriage return, and \n a newline):

```
jrepl "|" "*\r\n" /l /m /x /f "wrappedFileName" /o "unwrappedFileName"
```

To wrap a file (reverse the process)

```
jrepl "*\r\n" "|" /l /m /x /f "unwrappedFileName" /o "wrappedFileName"
```

If you put either command within a batch script, then you must use `call jrepl` instead of `jrepl`. This is because JREPL is also a batch script, so control will not return to your script unless you use CALL.

Comment: Really great answer, thank you and very thorough. This efficiently unwrapped my file and left an (easily removed) asterisk at the end of each line. This is great. Thank you for the help very much. 

I wasn't aware of JREPL (I actually only joined the group yesterday). Thank you!

Comment: And I see after running this that the asterisk is there due to my own lack of clarity in the question above. 
Regardless, I got it to work thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Split file into 5kB chunks:

```
set file="x.edb"
set max=5000

REM Findstr line limit 8k
REM Workaround: wrap in an archive to generate CRLF pairs for chunks > 8kB

for %i in (%file%) do (
set /a num=%~zi/%max% >nul      &REM No. of chunks
set /a last=%~zi%%max% >nul     &REM size of last chunk
if %last%==0 set /a num=num-1       &REM ove zero byte chunk
set size=%~zi
)

ren %file% %file%.0

for /l %i in (1 1 %num%) do (
set /a s1=%i*%max% >nul
set /a s2="(%i+1)*%max%" >nul
set /a prev=%i-1 >nul

echo Writing %file%.%i
type %file%.!prev! | (
  (for /l %j in (1 1 %max%) do pause)>nul& findstr "^"> %file%.%i)

FSUTIL file seteof %file%.!prev! %max% >nul
)
if not %last%==0 FSUTIL file seteof %file%.%num% %last% >nul
echo Done.
```

Tested on Win 10